# Considering Tyk API Gateway - open source version

Tags: open-source, api-gateway, tyk

**Project background:** Building an API driven Learning Management System. The back-end system will be receiving data from multiple systems and interfaces: web, mobile, VR.

Looking at API Gateways to front our APIs. Preferably an Open Source API gateway but need to be sure that the support and service is available. Tried out Tyk.io and it feels like it might be the way to go. Been reading other StackOverflow threads around this and looks like TYK's gateway fairs quite well against the likes of Kong and WSO2.

Main areas of consideration for us are:

1. Rate-limiting
2. Open ID Connect authentication
3. Analytics
4. Scalability
5. Hybrid model of hosting - combination of on-prem and cloud depending on compliance requirements of educational institutes (Probably rules of AWS' gateway)

It would be really helpful if anyone who is using or has used TYK.io for their production projects can share their experience, especially for enterprise clients/projects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Full disclosure: I work for [Tyk](http://tyk.io), so of course think that Tyk is the best fit for your project ;)

Seriously, though - Tyk can do all those things you’re after. Here are some links to the documentation for each item that is big on your list:

- [Rate-limiting](https://tyk.io/docs/control-limit-traffic/rate-limiting/)
- [Open ID Connect authentication](https://tyk.io/docs/security/your-apis/openid-connect/)
- [Analytics](https://tyk.io/docs/analyse/)
- [Scalability](https://tyk.io/docs/deploy-tyk-premise-production/)
- [Hybrid model of hosting](https://tyk.io/docs/get-started/with-tyk-hybrid/)

You can also post on the [Tyk community](https://community.tyk.io/) for help, if you haven’t already, or search to see what else others have said.

The Tyk Open Source API Gateway will do everything you need, even outputting analytics to difference sources, like ElasticSearch, Mongo or just CSV.

In addition, you can also use our API Management Platform to control your open source gateway. The Tyk API Management platform includes a Dashboard with analytics and out-of-the-box developer portal. Tyk is free to use, under a developer license, to manage a single gateway node, ideal if you are doing a POC.

Hope this helps and please keep in touch to let us know more about your use case.